# cloud functions deployment failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function (hello world) from a Cloud Source Repository, I get a deployment failure without any helpful info ...

===== EDIT =====

Problem was at Google's end.

Additional info at https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/20001

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Platform is having issues with deployments at the moment. From what I understand, they are working on it. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/853#issuecomment-571678764 You can see the status of the platform on https://status.cloud.google.com/.

Comment: Additional info at https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/20001.

Answer (score 0):

Try again a couple of times, there is a faliure reported in the GCloud Functions page.  We've had the same issue during the morning, and retrying has proved to be a workaround.